# How to filter a pivot table by the maximum value for each category?

Tags: python

I've created a pivot table for the number of wins of each international team for each decade...

grouped = data.groupby('decade').agg({'winner':'value_counts'})

```
        winner
decade  winner  
1870    Scotland     8
        England          3
1880    Scotland     23
        England          16
        Wales            8
        Canada           1
        Northern Ireland 1
        United States    1
1890    England          24
        Scotland     19
        Northern Ireland 4
        Wales            3
```

How do i filter this table so i get the international team with the most wins for each decade?

Tried using the max() method but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you could avoid the intermediate step and using [`groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with [`mode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mode.html) directly:

```
data.groupby('decade')['winner'].agg(pd.Series.mode)
```

Output:

```
decade
1870    Scotland
1880    Scotland
1890     England
Name: winner, dtype: object
```

Alternatively:

```
data.groupby('decade').agg({'winner': lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]})
```

If you already have `grouped`:

```
grouped.drop(columns='winner').reset_index().groupby('decade').first()
```

Output:

```
          winner
decade          
1870    Scotland
1880    Scotland
1890     England
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use methods like `size`, `reset_index` and `idxmax` to get your desired result:
import pandas as pd

```
# data
data = pd.DataFrame({
    'decade': [1870, 1870, 1870, 1880, 1880, 1880, 1880, 1880, 1880, 1890, 1890, 1890, 1890],
    'winner': ['Scotland', 'Scotland', 'England', 'Scotland', 'England', 'Wales', 'Canada', 'Northern Ireland', 'United States', 'England', 'Scotland', 'Northern Ireland', 'Wales']
})

# Group by decade and find the team with the most wins in each decade
grouped = data.groupby(['decade', 'winner']).size().reset_index(name='counts')
idx = grouped.groupby('decade')['counts'].idxmax()
result = grouped.loc[idx, ['decade', 'winner']]

print(result)
```

Here we first groups the data by both 'decade' and 'winner' and calculates the count of wins for each international team within each decade. This is achieved by using `groupby(['decade', 'winner'])` method and then applying `size()` to count the occurrences of each team in each decade. The resulting DataFrame ('grouped') includes an additional 'counts' column, representing the number of wins.

Now to determine the international team with the most wins for each decade, Within each decade group, it identifies the index ('idx') corresponding to the maximum count of wins, effectively pinpointing the team with the most wins in that specific decade.